# JavaScript - Drawing objects off the screen and other game optimizations

Tags: javascript, performance, p5.js

In my game a large map exists, and I am wondering if not drawing shapes (average 250+ at a time) when the player cant see them would make any difference in the game's performance.

Also, every frame I am checking the distance of the player to about 500+ other position vectors (used for enemies, food, bullet interactions), which takes a lot of square rooting. If I make a raw estimate just using the X and Y components combined, would that significantly boost game performance?

Comment: Any other ways of boosting the performance of the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to answer these questions is to try it and see what happens. You have to weigh the cost of calculating whether something is on the screen against the cost of drawing it. Again, you're going to have to measure both and decide for yourself.

As for measuring distance, you could try using the distance squared to avoid the square root.

Or you could try storing your objects in a data structure like a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), which allow you to you only check the distance of nearby objects. Or putting it simpler: do you really need all 500 vectors active all of the time? Why not store them and only activate them when you need them?

But again, the only way to answer your question is to try it. We can't tell you whether this will vastly improve performance in your game. Only you can answer that, by trying things out. Good luck.

Comment: my man Kevin! I will be sure to research about the distance squared method, and storing objects in a "quadtree", thank you for your help once again.

Comment: @Canatron No problem. The distance squared formula is just the distance formula without the final square root. It's a good way to compare distances if you don't need to know actual numbers. And quadtree is just one way. There are simpler ways, like just storing the objects in a different `ArrayList` for each "zone" the player can enter.

Comment: The math wasn't lagging the game, it was drawing all those shapes! I gave the player a "render distance" a circle around them which the player could not see past (the circle is larger than the screen of course... so nothing seems different) but the difference in performance is very noticable! (Up until the point the player becomes so large that they are able to see the ENTIRE map, at which all shapes must be drawn...